# Running tomcat from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have tomcat setup from eclipse, so I don't have to copy the war over every time to the server. I followed some online tutorial (don't recollect which one) to set it up. I see the below issue when I click on publish -

[image]

I clicked on add and remove of my project, and published again. No change. Its still grayed out. I have set it up in such a way, that all the logs I'd typically see on the server can now be viewed on my local machine. I can't recollect how I did the setup, but as of now, I see the logs aren't getting populated either. Can anyone please help me with both these issues?

Comment: Are you doing a clean publish after removing and adding the project

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy a Tomcat application "in-place", by putting a custom `<Context>` element in your server.xml. This context can refer to a `/www` folder within your project, with your project output-path set to compile into `/www/WEB-INF/classes`.

For example:

```
<!-- JobRoute;  run from within Eclipse project.
 -->
<Context docBase="C:/WS/jobRoute/www" path="/jr" reloadable="true">
</Context>
```

Tomcat will then automatically run & reload from the /www folder within your project, can reload automatically when you recompile (if you want), and no deployment whatsoever is necessary.

Typically we use this technique & add a shortcut to start Tomcat (in debug mode) under "External Tools" in Eclipse.

As for your "Eclipse - Tomcat" builtin integration, I've never found them to work well (always difficult to configure, and generally either didn't work or awkward & slow) and gave up on those long ago. So no tips from me there.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I already have that. Your answer doesn't completely solve my problem though :) Although I do a clean publish, I am still seeing issues. Any idea about the grayed out area? On what might help to fix it?

Comment: If you're running Tomcat in-place from your actual workspace application, you don't need to use the "servers", "publish" or any of those GUIs. Only thing you need is to start Tomcat, and (if you want to debug) create an eclipse Debug configuration specifying `localhost` and the debug port.